# Adding server proxy settings to Ant build file.

Tags: maven, ant, proxy, makefile

I have an ant build file that is part of a larger makefile I think there are also some maven calls from ant as well but for now I think the problem is with ant build. . I'm having problems when ant tries to make calls to an external URL for downloading some dependencies.

Once it tries to reference the URL the build fails and I get a

> BUILD FAILED>>>  /path../../build.xml:235: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused

Where and How do I add these proxy settings for Ant to work properly? In my same directory I do have a build.properties file but I could also maybe add it in the makefile or build.xml file.  How is this done with username and password for proxy as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [Setproxy task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/setproxy.html)

Answer (score 1):

While the `setproxy` task will set the proxy settings for Ant, they might not apply to the Maven build, if you are using the `artifact:mvn` build task.

You can however [set the proxy using a Maven settings file](http://maven.apache.org/ant-tasks/usage.html#The_Settings_File):

```
<settings>
  <proxies>
    <proxy>
      <protocol>http</protocol>
      <host>proxy.example.com</host>
      <port>8080</port>
      <nonProxyHosts>localhost</nonProxyHosts>
    </proxy>
  </proxies>
</settings>
```

And registering this settings file using the `artifact:dependencies` build task:

```
<artifact:dependencies settingsFile="maven-settings.xml" />
```

Comment: I am having the same issue. Trying to use ant which also needs some files from maven. I have a builld.xml file and settings.xml file that has the proxy information. How do I place settings.xml file into build.xml for ant?